# MATLAB: Residual error in Cramer's rule

Tags: matlab

I am quite familiar with Cramer's rule and I know why it is "useless". However, I got curious when the residual using the code below gives something like xxxxE-016 where xxxx represent numbers. I have tried the code below with 3 to 10 matrix sizes of floating system of linear equation.

Why is the residual error minimal?

Am I missing the right syntax for `disp(['norm of Cramer's rule residual = ' num2str(norm(A*x-b),4)])` in the code for getting such minimal error?

The code I provided is working perfectly, only doubting the syntax I used for the norm

```
      function x=cramerr(A,b)
        A=input('matrix A =');
        b=input('vector b =');
        n=size(A,1);
        m=size(A,2);
        tic;
      if n~=m
           Error ('The matrix is not square!');
           x=[];
      else
          detA=det(A);
     if det(A)~=0
          x=zeros(n,1);
     for j=1:n
         if j~=1 & j~=n
             Ab=[A(:,1:j-1) b A(:,j+1:n)];
        elseif j==1
             Ab=[b A(:,2:n)];
        elseif j==n
             Ab=[A(:,1:n-1) b];
        end
            x(j)=det(Ab)/detA;
         end %for j=1:n
    else 
          Error('The matrix A has a zero determinant');
          x=[];
   end % if det(A)~=0
       toc;
        disp(['norm of Cramer's rule residual = ' num2str(norm(A*x-b),4)]);
  end % if n~=m
```

Please you can use this as an example

```
    A =[0.373,0.296;0.326,0.260]; 
    b =[0.521;0.456];
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? Your code is difficult to read.

Comment: The code seems normal at my end here. However, I will adjust as you request

Comment: Just because a method is unstable doesn't meant that it will always give you a wrong answer. It just means that it *might* not give you the precise answer, which is enough to avoid it. That small error you get is roughly equal to `eps(1)`, the machine precision. This means that for your case Cramer's rule is correct within machine precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is a problem per se. What you do when you use Cramer's rule is solve the linear system of equations. In Matlab, you can simply do that with `x=inv(A)*b`, which uses a different algorithm to calculate the inverse (LU decomposition). In the Matlab page on Inverses and Determinants it says:

> If A is square and nonsingular, the equations AX = I and XA = I have
>   the same solution, X. This solution is called the inverse of A, is
>   denoted by A-1, and is computed by the function inv. The determinant
>   of a matrix is useful in theoretical considerations and some types of
>   symbolic computation, but its scaling and round-off error properties
>   make it far less satisfactory for numeric computation. Nevertheless,
>   the function det computes the determinant of a square matrix.

If you want to check the precision of both you could do this:

```
format long
built_in=inv(A)*b
own_function=r(A,b)
```

and compare the results. What I got was:

```
built_in=   [1.000000000000000;0.500000000000000]
own_function=    [1.000000000000054;0.500000000000000]
```

You can see where the small norm comes from. With this in mind such an error is most likely due to rounding off errors.

As for the formatting of `disp(['norm of Cramer's rule residual = ' num2str(norm(A*x-b),4)])` I would skip the apostrophe (`'`) in Cramer's as this will cause errors.

Comment: Thank you @ptev with all your suggestions. I have seen the gaps/errors as you have pointed out. However, I do not fully understand your last statement. " As for the formatting of disp(['norm of Cramer's rule residual = ' num2str(norm(A*x-b),4)]) I would skip the apostrophe (') in Cramer's as this will cause errors."

Comment: Oh, sorry - I meant you should write `Cramers` in the line with `disp` instead of `Cramer's`. The extra `'` breaks up the string and causes Matlab to give an error. My suggestion is simply:
`disp(['norm of Cramers rule residual = ' num2str(norm(A*x-b),4)]) `